# Waiting reply from ajax.googleapis.com

Tags: jquery

I have added jQuery to my webiste from google. The awful part is the completly slowness of google server. Sometime my website stops while trying to loading jquery from googleapis:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Can i do something? It's better to load jquery from other servers ? (maybe mine?)
When the "waiting reply from ajax.google" appears i can stay 30min waiting and nothing happens, I have to reload the page to show  it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my case, I found its better to NOT use external CDN.

1. You don't have power over it, Google can stop serving a version of jQuery
2. On page load, it means 1 HTTP request to 1 different host (not good since browser does parallel queries)
3. Most of the time you use a minifier so you can include the jQuery lib in your big minified file to reduce HTTP requests

And I found that Google CDN is *very* slow... I constantly get "**Waiting for ajax.google.....**"

Comment: The 4th point should be: the chances to have the same version of jQuery for another website (to use cache instead of new copy) are very very slim, considering that jQuery versions are constantly changing and the browser cache is limited. And the 5th point, which no one is considering, is privacy.

Comment: Absolutely right! Privacy should be in number 1, but you can see it's a cookie less domain, whereas with Facebook JS SDK (since almost every web sites include FB SDK JS) Facebook knows exactly what web page you are viewing.

Comment: I wonder why it's slow. Google has enough money and interest in making it fast, so websites would load faster. it's one of their main concerns..

Comment: Don't know too, but it's a very common problem (http://www.analyticsmarket.com/blog/tracking-code-slows-my-site). The worst thing is google static files should be cached by the browser, but browser is always re-asking for them.

Answer (score 5):

I've never had a problem with it.

On a side note, you should always use the full version of jquery.  e.g. -

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js
```

You lose the caching benefits if you use simply 1.4 or 1.5.

Here's a pretty good article about why you should use the Google CDN:

http://encosia.com/2008/12/10/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Comment: maybe this slowness was because i selected 1.4. But google should me smarted and provide a cache for 1.4 too

Comment: The reason that 1.4 isn't set to cache for long is that it cannot, by definition.  Since you're requesting the latest 1.4 version, that needs to return 1.4.4 today, but what if 1.4.5 is released tomorrow?  If the CDN were to send 1.4 with a far-future expires header, it couldn't guarantee that your 1.4 reference would always load the very latest 1.4 version in every browser - for up till the expires header's maximum future duration.

Comment: @dave: jquery 1.5.1 is out, 1.4 can be cached forever from now on

Comment: I don't know if that's a reasonable assumption. jQuery UI often updates the previous version with bugfixes even after it isn't the most current. If a show stopping IE9 bug surfaces in 1.4.4 or 1.3.2, I wouldn't be surprised to see a 1.4.5 or 1.3.3.  That scenario would be one of the worst possible times for long caching on the 1.3 or 1.4 reference to cause it to be unable to guarantee the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use google CDN then loading from your server. Most of the users already have jQuery from google cached and don't even have to load it. Read the 3 reasons why you should use google to load your jQuery  http://encosia.com/2008/12/10/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

You can also try loading jQuery from microsoft CDN at

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js

You can also have jQuery load from your server in case it wasn't loaded from google. You do that by writing

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')
{
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/jquery-1.5.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think it's ever _better_ or _ideal_ to outright rely on someone else.  Thomas Decaux made a good point and it's always slow for me.  In development I constantly find myself waiting for either a google font, some google cse stuff, or something google-related. Using a CDN is great, but use your own don't rely on someone else.

Comment: I think to implement this, is a bad idea, because ONLY after `ajax.googleapis.com` will timeout you will get a local copy, is it not?

Comment: @mmmshuddup - The whole point of a global google CDN is so **everyone** will have the same file (ideally) thus, so ideally the whole internet will have the same version cached (or at least a minimum number of versions. google CDN is always up and won't go away anywhere. only it's speed is questionable.

Comment: @vsync Agreed. It can be annoyingly slow sometimes, but the benefits which you mentioned make it worth it.

Comment: @vsync Google CDN isn't always up. Had an issue last week where a node  of the CDN was down for my area and a huge chunk of the web broke for me. Not cool.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I was having atrocious load times from chrome (2m+) with a codebase then I discovered it was using:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/...        # slow
```

Switching away from `https` in the code fixed it, now it's lightning fast (as long as you're online):

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/...         # fast
```

Sorry OP, I see you're not using `https` but perhaps this will help others. But wrt the original thread I prefer to have control and be able to do offline development, and if you put static assets on a good CDN it's a much of a muchness whether you use Google's or your own.  But if you want something fast for others without hiring a CDN it's a tradeoff, as others have said, between relying on Google's CDNs (which could go away at some point, though not likely soon) or setting up your own or giving your users a slower load time.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while and this is an old issue.

Similar things happened to me and I can assure you it s not because of google's cdn. In my case it only happens for in the Google Chrome not Firefox or Internet Explorer (not event IE can you believe it) so I decided to remove html parts one by one and turns out it s space entities in the html like tons of `&nbsp;` some how Chrome cannot handle them correctly (tries to replace them all I think) and this cause the problem and always show waiting message.

Basically the content guy used these entities to for correcting layout of some data. I used a simple table instead and fixed my problem.

This one about one year ago and I also sent a bug report to Google using Chrome. well I am not sure it has been fixed or not.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Just happened to me too. Re-installing Chrome resolved the issue